# VSCODE: I want to do "git merge --squash" from vscode

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I have a master branch that is the production branch and so I create several other branches for fixes and defects. I make several changes in those branches and so I commit many times in those branches. As per the policy, I have to create a single commit for a defect in the master branch for a fix but when I merge my changes to master branch all the commits are also merged and so is reflected in the history.

I want to know if there is an option in VSCode to squash merge to the master branch from my defect branch, so I can just create a single commit in the master branch and push.
I know how to do it in git bash but is there an alternative in VScode that I am not aware of?

Comment: do you merge your branches locally?

Comment: yes, I merge my defect branch into the local master branch and do a git push but as per the company policy we need to create a single commit for each defect, Presently I am using git command line to do so. I am looking for vscode alternative as I use it for dev.

Comment: Why not just add a `.gitconfig` attribute for this specific branch that always squashes? I don’t think downloading and bloating up your vscode experience with an extension for every need is in your best interest, especially if you’re using an extension for only 1 feature like this. This way it’s in your gitconfig and applied regardless of the UI or application you use.

Comment: An alternative solution is [here](https://dannyherran.com/2020/06/git-squash-commit-vs-code/)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [git graph](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mhutchie.git-graph) extension has this feature - [image: Usage example]

The recording above assumes that the current checked-out branch is the branch you want to merge *into* (e.g. in the recording that branch is called `master`), and the branch that we want to merge is the branch that gets right-clicked (e.g. in the recording that branch is called `fix_branch`).

Since this is a squash merge, the `fix_branch` doesn't really get merged into `master`, a single squash-merge commit gets created on top of `master`. This new commit has just the previous commit marked as a parent, rather than the usual 2-parent commit that we get in regular non-squash merges.

Comment: Could you expand your explanation please? What's the branch you are standing when doing this? What do you do after you do this?

Comment: Added a couple of paragraphs under the recording. Let me know if that clarifies it enough or if there's something else missing

Comment: Is there a way to have the "standard/common" behavior of the 2-parent commits? i mean, a first commit on the fix branch to squash all the commits done during development and a second commit to actually merge the fix-branch onto the master one? having a graph with all those branches ending on their own and not getting back to the master really hurt my ocd

Comment: Sounds like what you're describing is an interactive rebase squashing the last n-1 commits then a no-fast-forward merge, is that accurate? I doubt the GUI can do it with one click, although it shouldn't be too hard to do that with the GUI with steps